# SvcUtil.exe vs Add Reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

Why would someone use SvcUtil.exe when Add Service Reference in VS.NET provides all the proxy classes you'll need?

Comment: Everyone doesn't use VS always.

Comment: But if you do, you probably won't use SvcUtil.exe?  Also, these proxies are C# classes.  So what else are they using if not VS.NET?

Comment: `csc` `MonodDevelop` `SharpDevelop`. I may also use it to later modify the proxy classes according to some custom needs.

Comment: svchf does not generate xamlx activities either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes Add Service Reference in VS fails to create a useful proxy. Instead it gives you an empty Reference.cs details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224525/wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs-due-to-duplexbinding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988260/wcf-error-reference-cs-is-blank-empty) file. I've created a series of bat files to call SvcUtil.exe to generate the proxy classes.

Comment: +1 but also, svcutil will sometimes let you see error messages that would be hidden by "Add Service Reference".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: VS 2019 finally shows those errors, but only creates clients for .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

Both svcutil.exe & 'Add Service reference' will use the same proxy generation code underneath. Think of 'Add service reference' as a UI way to generate proxy where it pre-populates a set of switches that you will have to do in svcutil command line. For example when you add service reference in VS the UI lets you to reuse types from referenced assemblies, specify the kind of proxy to be generated (sync-async / task based etc). svcutil will also be useful if you want to automate service reference generation.