# Unable to instantiate service in client app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio

For some reason I cannot instantiate the class nor access the namespace of WCF service references I add to my VS2010 project. I had this problem last week too and I solved it by creating a new client project, however I don't want to do that every other day when I need to add a service reference.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you tried to repair Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I'll try that right away. Will report back with the result.

Comment: Sadly it did not help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution at [Sometimes adding a WCF Service Reference generates an empty reference.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs)

I chose to configure the service reference and unchecked "Reuse types in referenced assemblies", that solved it!