# Adding Service Reference for WCF Service generates empty reference.cs

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service-reference

I have seen this question before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409065) for one), however the solution is to not reuse referenced assemblies.
I need to reuse included assemblies because multiple services reference the same shared Objects.
If I do not reuse the assemblies I get namespace errors because the same Object is referenced through
different namespaces. (ie. Service1.Object, Service2.Object)

In short, I need the generated Client class that extends the ClientBase for the web service but I cannot untick the reuse referenced assemblies as I need shared Objects with the same namespace. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sometimes adding a WCF Service Reference generates an empty reference.cs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your client proxy with **svcutil.exe** and use the **/r** switch to specify assemblies that you want referenced instead of re-emitted in the auto-generated client proxy code.

- ProjACommon
- ProjBSvc

  - References ProjACommon
- ProjCClient

  - References ProjACommon
  - You want a client that references ProjA types and/or code rather than them being auto-generated into a new namespace within C

After building ProjBSvc exec the following, which outputs .wsdl & .xsd

```
svcutil.exe ProjBSvc.dll
```

2nd consume the wsdl & xsd to generate a proxy/client:

```
svcutil.exe *.wsdl *.xsd /o:<ProjCClientPath>/Client.cs /r:ProjACommon.dll
```

ProjCClient references Client.cs generated from previous steps

Build and examine with the object browser and you will see the types in C referencing the types in A instead of new types with the same name in C's namespace.
You may want `/tcv` and `/n` as well as other switches to meet your needs.

Here is an [article](http://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/generating-wcf-service-proxy-classes-using-svcutil/) that may help.  It also links to the [Microsoft documentation for svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

Comment: Can you reference a good example or link where I can get more details on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a mapper, meaning you will have to duplicate the models(objects) and have a class the maps the objects from one namespace to the next.