# Disable automatic generation of datasources file when updating service references

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We have a large solution with many service references and each time we need to update a service reference some .datasource files are generated. The problem with this is that these files have very long names and break the build process since the server that builds the solution can't handle such long names. As now we need to open up the servcice reference and manually delete the .datasource files. We don't have the rights to setup a rules blocking the files from checking which means that the update service references breaks the build from now and then.

We are using TFS 2008 and a project build in VS 2012

Is there any way to disable the autogeneration of these files?

Comment: Thanks that was a nice article, haven't been able to check if it helps or not yet.

Comment: may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem ,
After I did not tried to reach a settlement ,

Add  servicereference - advanced -add web reference and write url than dizayn 
 client code.example

```
MobilServiceReference.MobileService service = new MobilServiceReference.MobileService();
secondLoginResponse = service.SecondLogin(password, sendedPassword, true, true, mobileTransactionHeader);
```

Regards,

Comment: This involves ordering the application to use the .NET 2.0 Framework instead , which would not be suitable in most cases.