# The Reference.cs file in a WCF service always returns an empty file in localhost mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I've read numerous posts on this, but none help at all...

My situation is actually very similar to others, however, it only affects me when I'm trying to debug locally. When using my actual PROD service, the Reference.cs file gets generated fine.

I also tried running the client under the VS development server and on Local IIS Web Server using IIS Express.

No errors occur during generation of the proxy and I have triple verified that my DEV client matches up to my DEV service.

If anyone has any solid ideas on how to resolve this, I would appreciate it since it is preventing me from debugging locally with my service.

Comment: did you try generating the proxy with svcutil.exe ?

Comment: What numerous posts have you read and tried?  Have you done the steps in this duplicate question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs?rq=1

Comment: RckLN & Chris: I've tried that even though my web service only needs the referenced assembly from another project. So, in this case, using just the one referenced assembly where I have my models is the correct way of getting them into my project. It's a specific dll. I'll check into the utility shortly...

Comment: Kiran, I checked out the following link, but there are so many options. Not being a WCF expert, how would I simply generate the proxy where my Reference.cs file isn't blank using this tool? If you could give an example or one in the link to follow, I would appreciate it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx