# Service reference from WSDL generates empty namespace

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I'm adding a Service Reference in Visual Studio from a third party WSDL, but it's not creating the proxy classes, just a file with an empty namespace:

The WSDL address is http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/sgt/sgt_ws.php?wsdl

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18052
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyApp.MyServiceReference {

}
```

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I ran the command

```
SvcUtil.exe /t:code "http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/sgt/sgt_ws.php?wsdl" /d:D:\test
```

and got the following errors:

> Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail: An exception was thrown
>   while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Referenced type
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is only valid for
>   encoded SOAP. XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/sgt/sgt_ws.php']/wsdl:portType[@name='sgt_ws_methodsPort']
>
> Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: There was an error importing
>   a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on. XPath to
>   wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/sgt/sgt_ws.php']/wsdl:portType[@name='sgt_ws_methodsPort']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/sgt/sgt_ws.php']/wsdl:binding[@name='sgt_ws_methodsBinding']
>
> Error: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail: There was an error importing a
>   wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on. XPath to
>   wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/sgt/sgt_ws.php']/wsdl:binding[@name='sgt_ws_methodsBinding']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/sgt/sgt_ws.php']/wsdl:service[@name='sgt_ws_methodsService']/wsdl:port[@name='sgt_ws_methodsPort']
>
> Warning: No code was generated. If you were trying to generate a
>   client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain
>   any valid contracts or services or because all contracts/services were
>   discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed
>   all the metadata documents to the tool.
>
> Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas
>   make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I added a `Web Reference` instead of a `Service Reference`.

[image]