# Incorrect WCF Service Reference / Empty Reference.cs file

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, service-reference

I have created a WCF service using Service Library template. Using the Service.dll generated, I have hosted the service in a console application.

However, when I add a Service Reference in my web project, on viewing the Service details in Object browser, it points to incorrect assembly in the object browser as shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

[image]

One possible issue could be that, while renaming the namespaces in my web project, I ended up renaming the namespace of Service project also. But even after fixing all the namespaces, I still have this issue.

Any ideas on what can be done to resolve it?

While adding a Service Reference, it displays the correct members/interfaces as shown in the screenshot below. Only when I view the Service Reference in the object browser, I don't see those interfaces exposed by the service.

[image]

### **Project dependencies of service project**

Not sure why the web project is a dependency of the Service library project? It should not be as I have not added any reference to it in the Service project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs) here after researching on this issue.

I also found out that the `reference.cs` file was empty in my case also. After unchecking `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` from 'Configure Service Reference' dialog, I was able to generate the Service reference client code successfully. My Service reference is now pointing to the correct Interface/members. In case of any queries, feel free to comment or contact me directly.